# Functional Programming Exercise

Tags: f#, functional-programming

As a functional programming exercise, I thought I'd write a little program to rank crafting recipes in an mmo by profitability.

In an OO language, I'd make strategy objects for each recipe, with Cost(), ExpectedRevenue(), and Volume() as members. I'd then put all the objects in a list and sort them by a profitability/time function.

Trying to accomplish the same result in F#, but I'm not certain how to go about it. I have some disjointed cost functions, for example:

```
let cPM (ss,marble) = (15.0 * ss + 10.0 * marble + 0.031) / 5.0
let cTRef (tear,clay) = (tear + 10.0 * clay + 0.031) / 5.0
```

and then revenue and volume definitions like:

```
let rPM = 1.05
let vPM = 50
```

but I'm not sure what to do now. Make a list of tuples that look like

```
(name: string, cost:double, revenue:double, volume:int)
```

and then sort the list? It feels like I'm missing something- still thinking in OO, not to mention adding new recipes in this fashion will be rather awkward.

Has anyone any tips to use the functional concepts in a better way? It seemed like this type of calculation problem would be a good fit for the functional style.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a fairly complex question with multiple possible answers.  Also, it is quite hard to guess anything about your domain (I don't know what game you're playing :-)), so I'll try to make something up, based on the example.

The basic functional approach would be to model the different recipes using a discriminated union.

```
type Recipe = 
  | FancySword of gold:float * steel:float // Sword can be created from gold & steel
  | MagicalStone of frogLegs:float // Magical stone requires some number of frog legs
```

Also, we need to know the prices of things in the game:

```
type Prices = { Gold : float; Steel : float; FrogLegs : float }
```

Now you can write functions to calculate the cost and expected revenue of the recipes:

```
let cost prices recipe = 
  match recipe with
  | FancySword(g, s) -> 
      // To create a sword, we need 2 pieces of gold and 15 pieces of steel
      2.0 * g * prices.Gold + s * 15.0 * prices.Steel
  | MagicalStone(l) -> l * prices.FrogLeg
```

This takes the record with all the `prices` and it takes a recipe that you want to evaluate.

The example should give you some idea - starting with a discriminated union to model the problem domain (different recipes) and then writing a function with pattern matching in it is usually a good way to get started - but it's hard to say more with the limited information in your question.

Comment: A good way to define the problem domain was definitely lacking in what I've tried so far. Not sure I follow however how to use the matching function, or the role of `g` and `s`. Aren't the quantities (`2.0`, `15.0`) and prices (`prices.Gold`, `prices.Steel`) already present in the lambda for FancySword? The game is Blade and Soul, btw :)

Comment: Yeah, my understanding of the problem is a bit limited :-). My idea is that there are some parameters of the recipe (you need some number of frog legs to create magical stone) and then you have some global value of gold in the game (that comes from `Prices`). If the cost does not depend on external prices, then you can put all the information in the `Recipe` cases - that's probably the case in your example.

Answer (score 1):

In functional languages you can do anything only with functions. Here you can define common profitability function and sort your recipes with it and `List.sortBy`:

```
// recipe type with constants for Revenue, Volume and (ss,marble)
type recipe = {r: float; v: float; smth: float * float}

// list of recipes
let recipes = [
    {r = 1.08; v = 47.0; smth = (28.0, 97.0)};
    {r = 1.05; v = 50.0; smth = (34.0, 56.0)} ]

// cost function
let cPM (ss,marble) = (15.0 * ss + 10.0 * marble + 0.031) / 5.0

// profitability function with custom coefficients
let profitability recipe = recipe.r * 2.0 + recipe.v * 3.0 + cPM recipe.smth

// sort recipes by profitability
let sortedRecipes =
    List.sortBy profitability recipes

// note: it's reordered now
printfn "%A" sortedRecipes
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is a little lacking in type safety, I think - you already stated that a FancySword is made of gold and steel, so you shouldn't have to remember to correctly pair the gold quantity with the gold price! The type system ought to check that for you, and prevent an accidental `g * prices.Steel` mistake.

If the set of possible resource types is fixed, then this is a nice use-case for Units of Measure.

```
[<Measure>] type Gold
[<Measure>] type Steel
[<Measure>] type FrogLegs
[<Measure>] type GameMoney

type Recipe = { 
                goldQty      : float<Gold>
                steelQty     : float<Steel>
                frogLegsQty  : int<FrogLegs>
              }

type Prices = {
                goldPrice     : float<GameMoney/Gold>
                steelPrice    : float<GameMoney/Steel>
                frogLegsPrice : float<GameMoney/FrogLegs>
              }

let recipeCost prices recipe = 
    prices.goldPrice      * recipe.goldQty         +
    prices.steelPrice     * recipe.steelQty        +
    // frog legs must be converted to float while preserving UoM
    prices.frogLegsPrice  * (recipe.frogLegsQty |> float |> LanguagePrimitives.FloatWithMeasure)

let currentPrices = {goldPrice = 100.0<GameMoney/Gold>; steelPrice = 50.0<GameMoney/Steel>; frogLegsPrice = 2.5<GameMoney/FrogLegs> }

let currentCost = recipeCost currentPrices    

let fancySwordRecipe = {goldQty = 25.4<Gold>; steelQty = 76.4<Steel>; frogLegsQty = 0<FrogLegs>}

let fancySwordCost = currentCost fancySwordRecipe
```

The compiler will now ensure that all calculations check out. In the `recipeCost` function, for example, it ensures that the total is a  `float<GameMoney>`.

Since you mentioned volume, I think you can see how you can replicate the same pattern to write type-safe functions that will calculate total recipe volumes as a value of type `int<InventoryVolume>`.